# Warning 'React hook useEffect has a missing dependency'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-effects

In a React app I get this warning on a few components in the useEffect function. I have seen other SO questions but still cant see a fix.

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'digiti' and 'time'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

```
const GenerateNumber = (props) => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    // add side effect to component
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(
            () => setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)),
            50
        );

        setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(interval); setNumber(props.digiti); }, props.times * 100);

    }, []);

    return (
        <span className='digit'>{number}</span>
    );
}
```

Comment: did you try this `[props.digiti, props.times];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something the react hooks exhaustive deps explain. In general, your dependency array should include all values used in the dependency array, however when you do this with something like `setNumber`, your useEffect hook will run infinitely as each change of `setNumber` triggers a new render (and each new render triggers `setNumber`, see the problem there?).

Your actual error, with the prop values of both `digiti` and `times` aim at you adding these two values to the dependency array, which would case the `useEffect` hook to run again every time these props change. It is up to you if this is intended behavior.

What is actually documented in the dependency array documentation is that it is intended behavior to leave the array empty to have the `useEffect` hook run exactly once.

Comment: Hendiks I plan to create an animation that runs like: https://codepen.io/Ahmed_B_Hameed/pen/LZqNmp?editors=0010 . Can you give me another suggestion?

Comment: Well as I mentioned, an empty dependency array is actually intended behavior. You can simply leave it empty and ignore the warning (or use your IDE's help to suppress the warning)